# normal epimorphisms

Tags: category-theory

In a category $\mathcal{C}$ consider the diagram
$$K\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B$$
with $k:K\longrightarrow A$ the kernel of $f:A\longrightarrow B$ and $f$ a cokernel. Is it true that $f$ is the cokernel of $k$?

Comment: I'm obligated to point out that kernels and cokernels don't make sense in an arbitrary category. But under the assumption that you have [zero morphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism), Ennar's answer works nicely.

Comment: @Alex, you are right. Though, this question probably raised in context of abelian categories in order to prove some basic facts like epi-mono factorization.

Comment: @Ennar yes exactly for that thanks for the answer

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun!

Comment: @AlexKruckman exactly I am working in pointed categories with kernels pullbacks binary sums, and proving that a category is so called normal when every regular epi of the category is normal (in the sense of being a cokernel)

Comment: Ok. It's always best to include the context for your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a cokernel of $g\colon C\to A$. Since $fg = 0$ and $k$ is kernel of $f$, there exists unique $\bar g\colon C\to K$ such that $g = k\bar g$. Now, let $h\colon A\to D$ such that $hk = 0$. This implies that $0 =hk\bar g = hg$. But $f$ is cokernel of $g$, so there exists unique $\bar h\colon B\to D$ such that $h = \bar h f$. Thus, $f$ is cokernel of $k$.